# counts the number of times a number appears in the series of numbers entered by a user

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning python so I am stuck and need your help. I am trying to write a program that allows users to enter numbers then when pressing '0' to exit, it outputs the number of times a certain number appears. if I want to do it for an already set list, for example finding the number of apearance for number 3:

```
list= (2, 400, 3, 40, 100, 3, 3, 10, 0)
print(list.count(3))
```

Could you please show me what I need to do if I want to create this so it is not to a set list but a user input to a series of numbers and exits to display the count when '0' is pressed?

My trial was so far as the following but obviously wrong as doesn't loop or end by inputting '0'. Please help.

```
print('Enter the next number(0 to finish)')
list1 = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
print(list1.count(3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
l = list()

curr_number = -1
while curr_number != 0:
    curr_number = int(input("Number: "))
    l.append(curr_number)
print("EXITED")

print(l.count(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where your input would end. You should just make a for loop that takes input one at a time, or ask the user for input once with space delimiting. Something like:

```
numbers = input("Enter the numbers")
list1 = ...
```

Otherwise you will continue to loop as `input().split()` changes every time you insert anything and it will never end.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
lst = []
while True:
    try:
        ans = int(input('enter the next number'))
    except ValueError:
        print('the value entered is not an integer')
    else:
        if ans == 0:
            print(lst.count(3))
            break
        else:
            lst.append(ans)
            continue
```

We are constructing an infinite loop with `while True` which we manually `break` when 0 is passed. As long as 0 is not passed and the input is an integer **or can be converted into one** the value is stored in the list and the user is prompted to provide yet another one.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
list1=list()
print('Enter the next number(0 to finish)')
while True:
  nr=input()
  if nr.isdigit():
    if int(nr)!=0:
      list1.append(int(nr))
    else:
      break
print(list1.count(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try with regex:

```
from re import match

user = ""

while(not match("^(\d+ )+0$", user)):
    user = input("Enter the next number (0 to finish) :")

user = [int(n) for n in user.split()[:-1]]
```

The regex :
`^...$` mean begin the analysis at the begining of the string and finish at its end.
`\d` mean 'I want a number' !
`+` mean i want the group before me at least once.
`(...)` define a group.

https://regex101.com/r/ShdA3Z/1

Answer (score 0):

```
myList = []
while True:
    number = int(input('Enter your number ( 0 to quit ): '))
    if number != 0:
        myList.append(number)
    else:
        break

choice = int(input('Enter the Number you want to check for occurrence: '))
print(myList.count(choice))
```

**RESULT**

```
Enter your number ( 0 to quit ): 1
Enter your number ( 0 to quit ): 2
Enter your number ( 0 to quit ): 1
Enter your number ( 0 to quit ): 3
Enter your number ( 0 to quit ): 1
Enter your number ( 0 to quit ): 4
Enter your number ( 0 to quit ): 0
Enter the Number you want to check for occurrence: 1
3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = []

while True:
    n = int(input())
    if number != 0:
        a.append(number)
    else:
        break

b = int(input())
print(a.count(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace NewC
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int d, num2 = 1, num3, counter = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("enter one digit positive number");
            d = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            while ( num2 != -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("enter integer positive number");
                num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                while ( num2 > 0)
                {
                    num3 = num2 % 10;
                    if (num3 == d)
                    {
                        counter++;
                        num2 = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        num2 = num2 / 10;
                    }
                }
                
            }
            Console.WriteLine(" the number" + d + " is repeated in" + counter + "numbers");
        }
    }
}
```